# Exchange 2003 - Using ExMerge.exe to export mailboxes fails with error (0x8004011d)

Tags: exchange-2003

I'm using ExMerge.exe to export some old mailboxes to PST format for archiving. I've followed instructions at 
    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124178%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx
and
    http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996410%28EXCHG.65%29.aspx

To make sure I have permissions appropriately setup.

However I get the message

```
[13:50:02] Error opening message store (MSEMS). Verify that the Microsoft Exchange Information Store service is running and that you have the correct permissions to log on. (0x8004011d)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Have you waited a while for cached permissions to be re-evaluated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permissions can be trickier than they might appear -- by default, Exchange full administrators still can't access every mailbox in a domain.

[See this page](http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Exmerge_error_0x8004011d_%28Exchange%29) for some suggestions on how to ensure you're using an account that can access every mailbox.

Comment: Yeah as per nedm's request, I went through the link. I re-enabled the user account object, and un-hid it form the Global Address List. Now the PST export worked fine. So it seems besides the mail store permissions you need the user account to be enabled and un-hid from the global address list.

Thanks, nedm!!!

P.S. The user account who's mailbox is being exported for archival was disabled and hidden from exchange lists, as part of our organization's initial accounts deactivation procedure.